# Working with glassfish and runninga a project on intelliji and the project build build and start up in debug but once i select run the project doesnt

Tags: javascript, java, intellij-idea, glassfish

ERROR: transport error 202: connect failed: Connection refused
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)

Comment: You try to connect to the debugger bit as a server on a port.  It has not been configured to listen to that port.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.